# clone the server in zabbix using api

Tags: bash, api, shell, zabbix

sorry guys, but i don't know how clone server in zabbix, so please help.
i didn't find the json request with this function in zabbix documentation, so try to create personal script, but when i get items from server and try to add it in new, have this error :

> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32602,"message":"Invalid
>   params.","data":"Item uses host interface from non-parent
>   host."},"id":1}

thanks

if need of course my code :

```
create_host() { 
a='{ "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "host.create", "params": { "host": "'$selected_name'", "interfaces": [ { "type": 1, "main": 1, "useip": 1, "ip": "'$IP'", "dns": "", "port": "10050" } ], "groups": [ { "groupid": "1" } ], "templates": [ { "templateid": "10001" } ], "inventory": { "macaddress_a": "01234", "macaddress_b": "56768" } }, "auth": "'$AUTH_TOKEN'", "id": 1 }'
        wget -O- -o /dev/null $API --no-check-certificate --header 'Content-Type: application/json-rpc' --post-data "$a"
}

push_items() {
id_of_host=`echo $3 | tr -d ']' | tr -d '[u' | sed -s  "s/'//g"`
echo "name"$1
echo "key"$2
request_push='{
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": "item.create",
        "params": {
                "name": "'$1'",
                "key_": "'$2'",
                "hostid": "'$id_of_host'",
                "type": 10,
                "value_type": 0,
                "interfaceid": "2",
                "delay": 300
                },
        "auth": "'$AUTH_TOKEN'",
        "id": 1
}'
        wget -O- -o /dev/null $API --no-check-certificate --header 'Content-Type: application/json-rpc' --post-data "$request_push"
}
get_items() {
request='{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "item.get",
    "params": {
        "output": ["name", "key_"],
        "host": "'$ETALON_SERVER'",
        "sortfield": "name"
    },
    "auth": "'$AUTH_TOKEN'",
    "id": 1
}'
        wget -O- -o /dev/null $API --no-check-certificate --header 'Content-Type: application/json-rpc' --post-data "$request"
}


AUTH_TOKEN=$(authenticate)

if [ -z "$AUTH_TOKEN" ]; then
        echo "Connection not established"
        exit 1
else
        echo "everything is ok"
       echo $AUTH_TOKEN
fi

check_host=$(check_exist_host)
host_create=$(create_host)
#echo "$host_create"
id_host=`echo "$host_create" | python -c 'import json, sys; print json.load(sys.stdin)["result"]["hostids"]'`
items=$(get_items)
#echo $items
keys=`echo "$items" | python -c 'import json, sys; print ("".join(i["name"]+";"+i["key_"] +"|" for i in json.load(sys.stdin)["result"]))'`
while IFS='[;]' read -r s1 s2; do
        name_item=$s1
        item_key=$s2
        push_items "$s1" "$s2" "$id_host"
done < <(printf "%b" "${keys//|/\\n}")
```

Answer (score 1):

As old as this question is, it still comes up in the top search results...

The API doesn't allow host.clone() because it's supposed to be performed through host.get() and host.create(), depending on your needs. The following code clones

- host name
- host visible name
- first IP address
- groups, adding a new one (static ID)
- macros

and changes

- templates (statid ID)

The old host is renamed and disabled, in order to maintain data history.

```py
from pyzabbix import ZabbixAPI
ZAPI = ZabbixAPI(api_url)
ZAPI.login(username, password)

batch_list = [
    "host1-asdasd",
    "host2-asdasd"
]

for hostname in batch_list:
    try:
        original_host = ZAPI.host.get(
            filter={'host': hostname},
            selectGroups='extend',
            selectInterfaces='extend',
            selectMacros='extend'
        )[0]
        disable = ZAPI.host.update(
            hostid=original_host['hostid'],
            status=1,
            host=original_host['host'] + '-history',
            name=original_host['name'] + ' (history)'
        )
        print(disable)
        clone = ZAPI.host.create(
            host=original_host['host'],
            name=original_host['name'],
            proxy_hostid=original_host['proxy_hostid'],
            groups=original_host['groups'] + [{'groupid': 802}],
            macros=original_host['macros'],
            interfaces=[{'main': '1', 'type': '1', 'useip': '1', 'dns': '', 'port': '10050', 'bulk': '1',
                         'ip': original_host['interfaces'][0]['ip']}],
            templates={'templateid': 25708}
        )
        print(clone)
    except:
        print('something went wrong with: ' + hostname)
```